# Install libmyodbc on Ubuntu Yakkety (16.10)

Tags: ubuntu, apt, odbc

How do I install libmyodbc on Yakkety?  It was in Xenial, but I'm getting `Package 'libmyodbc' has no installation candidate`

any thoughts?  It's necessary for another piece of software i'm trying to install.

Answer (score 1):

The package `libmyodbc` was [removed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/myodbc/+bug/1564856) from [Ubuntu Xenial](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/libmyodbc) and it is not available in the Ubuntu Yakkety repository. (It isn’t compatible with MySQL 5.7 and later.)

> No description available for libmyodbc in ubuntu xenial.

It is only available for [Precise, Trusty, and Vivid](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/myodbc).